# Unable to login to heroku account

Tags: heroku

When I try to login to my heroku account in a web browser, the page just refreshes and does nothing.
If I give it wrong credentials then it shows the error message.

I tried using cli but it opens the browser and gets stuck on the same loop.

Used other browsers both on windows and android, resetted the password, used vpn, asked a friend, all results in the same refresh thing.

Asked the account-lockout heroku email id, it plain out autorejected my mail because the mail has a '.' inbetween.

Heroku Mail id

`firstlast@gmail.com`

Gmail id

`first.last@gmail.com`

I looked up other links over here and on other sites as well to no avail.

If I use help.heroku.com and then goto dashboard, it shows the loading animation and then goes back to the login page

Any help on this would be seriously appreciated